# VimL/Vimscript: how to access local variable of outer function from its inner function?

Tags: vim, scope, closures, scoping

I have a function of the following form:

```
function! s:my_function(dict_arg)
    let darg = copy(a:dict_arg)

    func! my_inner_func(cond)
        if a:cond ==# 'a'
            execute darg.a
        elseif a:cond ==# 'b'
            execute darg.b
        elseif a:cond ==# 'c'
            execute darg.c
        endif
    endfunc

    return function('my_inner_func')
endfunc
```

Where the argument passed to the `dict_arg` parameter will be some dict keyed with `a`, `b` and `c`, with their respective values being strings representing Ex commands that will be executed depending on the specific `cond` (condition).

The purpose of the outer function `s:my_function` is to generate a Funcref that will execute the appropriate Ex command (`darg.a`, `darg.b` or `darg.c`) based on the `cond`, which is itself determined elsewhere by other variables.

**So my problem is that I don't know how to reference the local variable `darg` defined in the scope of `s:my_function` from within `my_inner_func`.** When the function is called, I get the error `E121: Undefined variable: darg`. It also doesn't work (same error) if I don't define the local variable `darg`, and instead just try to do `execute a:dict_arg.b` for instance.

I can get around it by defining `darg` to be global, as in `let g:darg = copy(a:dict_arg)`, then later doing `execute g:darg.a`. But of course, I'd like to avoid that.

In something like Python, this type of lexical scope resolution is automatic. But VimL is well.. VimL. Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In something like Python, this type of lexical scope resolution is automatic

In VimScript, except lambdas, it's *manual*. You have to explicitly add `closure` keyword:

```
func! my_inner_func(cond) closure
    ...
endfunction
```

> The purpose of the outer function s:my_function is to generate a Funcref that will execute the appropriate Ex command (darg.a, darg.b or darg.c) based on the cond, which is itself determined elsewhere by other variables.

IMO, it's better to use "a partial".

```
function! InnerFunc(foo, bar, baz)
    ...
endfunction
...
let OuterFunc = function('InnerFunc', ["FOO", "BAR"])
call OuterFunc("BAZ")
```